# Unable to resolve ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration on EMR when running PIG

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-pig, amazon-emr, emr

I have been trying to run a very simple task with Pig on Amazon EMR. When I run the commands in interactive shell, everything works fine. But when I ran the same thing as batch job, I get

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017: Internal
>   error creating job configuration.

and the running the script fails.
Here's my 7 line script. It's just computing averages over tuples of Google bigrams. mc is match count and vc is volume count.

```
bigrams = LOAD 's3n://<<bucket-name>>/gb­bigrams/*' AS (bigram:chararray, year:int, mc:int, vc:int);
grouped_bigrams = group bigrams by bigram;
answer1 = foreach grouped_bigrams generate group, ((DOUBLE) SUM(bigrams.mc))/COUNT(bigrams) AS avg_mc;
sort_answer1 = ORDER answer1 BY avg_mc desc;
answer2 = LIMIT sort_answer1 5;
STORE answer1 INTO 's3n://<bucket-name>/output/bigram/20130409/answer1';
STORE answer2 INTO 's3n://<bucket-name>/output/bigram/20130409/answer2';
```

I was guessing the error has to something to do with STORE and s3 path. So I have tried various combinations like using $OUTPUT, backslashes, etc. But keep getting the same error.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Run the script line by line (with DUMP at the end of each section) and identify in which line you are failing. It can be your LOAD (wrong schema), STORE (wrong permissions), Casting, wrong number of brackets..

Comment: Hey @Guy, Thanks for your response. My issue is actually resolved. My bucket name in the script had a hyphen and I had copied the name from a pdf. Somehow the hex of the hyphen after pasting came out to be ad instead of 2d, which was messing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the S3 Block File System instead of the native file system?

e.g.

```
s3://<<bucket-name>>/gb­bigrams/*
s3://<bucket-name>/output/bigram/20130409/answer1
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that. But the problem was with the hexcode of my bucket name. It contained a hyphen but while copy-pasting names, it got a different one as opposed to the default one.